# JSTL implicit objects not working as expected

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

Printing implicit object with JSTL 1.1.2 gives me pointers instead of expected values!

Output:

```
cookie=[Ljava.lang.String;@52a96147
cache-control=[Ljava.lang.String;@6e31a6b6
connection=[Ljava.lang.String;@7db82f3e
accept-language=[Ljava.lang.String;@4725cfed
host=[Ljava.lang.String;@375f519
accept=[Ljava.lang.String;@352e3e15
user-agent=[Ljava.lang.String;@6eedeff9
accept-encoding=[Ljava.lang.String;@4725fd54
accept-charset=[Ljava.lang.String;@f1aba4a
This is JSTL
```

Source:

```
<ul>
        <c:forEach var="aHeader" items="${headerValues}">
            <li>${aHeader}</li>
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>
    <c:out value="This is JSTL"/>
```

I have include <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> in JSP and also have jstl.jar and standard.jar inside WEB-INF/lib added to build path.
Using Glassfish 3.1.2.and Servlet 3.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Printing implicit object with JSTL 1.1.2 gives me pointers instead of expected values!

On what basis are you expecting anything else? All those methods return header values which are supplied as `String[]` objects.

Comment: My mistake...i ment to display header values, so header implicit object, fits better.